# AngularJS in Internet Explorer 9 no Template Data Displayed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-9

I am using AngularJS in concert with Django, which necessitated changing the interpolation's template tags, which I have changed from Django-esque `{{` and `}}` to ASP or Underscore-ish `<%` and `%>`.

```
app.config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%').endSymbol('%>');
}
```

This works excellently in all browsers I have tested except for Internet Explorer 9. It's not that the data is not loading with $resource, there's a couple of `<img>` tags with `ng-src` set from that retrieved data and it displays properly, and some `<input>` elements with `ng-model` also bound to some of the data that works properly as well. **It's only the `<% template %>` tags that don't work.**

I can't switch back to default template tags as that will conflict with Django. I am using a fairly old version of Django that does not have a `{% verbatim %}` tag.

I'm baffled.

Comment: Have you tried symbols other than `<%` and `%>`? IE may just be picky about those. It wouldn't be the first time IE has been picky...

Comment: Switching from <% and %> to {[{ and }]} seemed to work. That's ugly though. :(
If you answer properly I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I suppose ugly is better than not functioning at all. Perhaps you could try something PHPish `<?` and `?>`Glad it worked out for you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried symbols other than `<%` and `%>`? IE may just be picky about those.

Comment: IE 9 will see any template symbol containing a "<" as a tag, and ignore it. I decided to use "{+" and "+}".